# XML pipeline in Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I'd like to do some DOM-stlye processing on a very big xml to convert some nodes into others.

This is an example of what I have

```
...
<node>
    <stuff>text-and-numbers</stuff>
</node>
...
```

And this is what I need to output

```
...
<node>
    <info>some text</info>
    <more>some text</more>
    <id>some text</id>
</node>
...
```

All the information inside the `<node>...</node>` output part is extracted programatically processing the `<node>text-and-numbers</node>` of the input. I mean, I have a function `getInfo(someText)` that returns the content of output's `<node>`.

I've got the code to do it in a DOM way, but the problem is that the XML is too big that it needs too much memory, so I'd like to do it in another way.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: are you getting this XML from a file?

Comment: Yes, but I've managed to reconstruct it in SAX, extending a a XMLWriter class I found on the net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should look into SAX or StAX.  The former means not having to keep the whole DOM tree in memory; the latter is a streaming parser.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with SAX is that it's quite difficult to "dump" all input XML to the output without writing quiet a lot of code. And I haven't found any "easy" examplo of StAX pipelining...

Comment: Choose your poison - write more code or rely on the DOM.  If your XML is that big, you don't have much choice.

Comment: Yes, I now... Do you have any "pipeline" StAX example that I can look for, to compare it agains SAX?

Comment: Nothing that's better than Google.